# How do I automatically answer y in bash script?

Tags: bash

I want to uninstall some program via a bash script. After I run the command, the terminal asking me if I am sure that I want to uninstall it. So I need to answer `y`. I want to do it automatically and answer `y` after delay of 10 seconds.

I did this example but it's not working -

```
#!/usr/bin
/opt/MNG/MNGVIEWHP/fe/uninstall
sleep 10
echo "y"
```

Any idea? 
Centos 7.2

Comment: ITYM, `#! /bin/bash -` instead of `#!/usr/bin`

Comment: check if the `uninstall` program accepts parameters or a config script or not. It'll be easier that way

Comment: Asked and answered *ad nauseam* across the web. "*it's not working"* is not a good decription of the problem. Perhaps you can state how your problem is different than the countless others.

Comment: What your script actually does: run `uninstall` and wait for it to exit.  Then sleep 10 seconds.  Then echo `y\n` to stdout (which is still connected to the terminal, not to stdin of any program)

Answer (score 98):

That's what the `yes` command is for. It outputs `y`s one per line indefinitely so it can be piped to commands that ask yes/no questions.

```
yes | /opt/MNG/MNGVIEWHP/fe/uninstall
```

That answers `y` to all questions. To answer `n` to all questions, replace `yes` with `yes n`. For a predefined mix of `y` and `n`, you can replace `yes` with:

```
printf '%s\n' y n n y y n...
```

Or run it as:

```
/opt/MNG/MNGVIEWHP/fe/uninstall << 'EOF'
y
n
n
y
y
n
EOF
```

If you do need the answer not to be available for reading before 10 seconds, you'd do:

```
(sleep 10; echo y; sleep 2; echo n;...) | /opt/MNG/MNGVIEWHP/fe/uninstall
```

But that would probably not be necessary, when we write `y` to the pipe, it's going to be there for `uninstall` to read it whenever it wants to read it, it's unlikely you'd need to wait for it to be ready to read it. The exception would be if `uninstall` decides to flush the input before asking the question.

All those assume the `uninstall` command just reads each answer as one line of input from its standard input.

For more complex cases, where the command reads the answers directly from the tty device or where you need to feed answers conditionally (for instance based on what the command outputs), that's where you'd use things like `expect` or `zsh`'s `zpty`.

Note that many interactive programs can enter some non-interactive mode when passed some option. You may want to check their manual first, before spending too much effort working around the problem.

Comment: Thanks! This is fine in case that we need to answer only for one question. What happened if we have to answer on 20 questions for example?

Comment: @Shalev, see edit.

Comment: Thanks ! So if I want to enter another values like interger (2 for example) I need to replace it instead of "y"?   
printf '%s\n' y n n y y n 2 3 n y | /opt/MNG/MNGVIEWHP/fe/uninstall

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: Thanks! last question: if I want to click on "enter" key - what I need to print?

Comment: @ShalevSason, in all the solutions I've gave, like with `echo "y"`, each time,  we write `y<newline>`, simulating you pressing `y` followed by Enter. If you want to simulate pressing Enter alone, that would be feeding an empty line, so `printf '%s\n' y n '' 2 3` (where `''` is the empty line).

Comment: Note that there are *some* programs that read not from stdin, but from the tty. For those, you can use the `expect` program.

Comment: @mpez0, that's already mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Should it be "replace `yes` with `n`" instead? It won't allow me to edit the answer.

Comment: @GitGud. No, there's generally no `n` command, but the `yes` command (not a POSIX command but ubiquitous as it was already there in Unix v7 in the 70s) takes an optional argument that is the text to repeat (`y` if not specified).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, of course. I actually know this, it was just a brain fart. Sorry!